# Prove that $1+20+20^2+20^3+....+20^{21} \equiv 0\bmod 23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

I am in search of a correct and shortcut techniques to prove this.

Otherwise I have calculated each remainder according to the power of $20$ to prove this :-

$1 \equiv 1 \bmod 23$
$\Rightarrow 20 \equiv -3\bmod 23$
$\Rightarrow 20^2 \equiv (-3)^2 \equiv 9\bmod 23$
$20^{2n}\equiv (-3)^{2n}\bmod 23$
$20^{2n-1}\equiv (-3)^{2n-1}\bmod 23$.

Therefore

$1+20+20^2+20^3+....+20^{21} \equiv 0\bmod 23$
For $\sum_{n=1}^{11} 20^{2n-1} \equiv r \bmod 23$
we have  $$-3-4+10-2+5-1-9+11+7-6-8 \equiv 0 \bmod 23$$

For $\sum_{n=0}^{10} 20^{2n} \equiv s \bmod 23$
we have   $$1+9+12+16+6+8+3+4+13+2-5 \equiv 0\bmod 23$$

Therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^{11} 20^{2n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{10} 20^{2n} \equiv r+s \bmod 23$$
$$\Rightarrow 1+20+20^2+20^3+....+20^{21} \equiv 0+0 \equiv 0\bmod 23$$

If possible just show any short-cut correct way to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you still want parentheses around the "mod 23" parts, try `\pmod{23}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that by [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

$$1+20+20^2+20^3+....+20^{21} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{21}(-3)^k=\frac{1- (-3)^{22} }{4} \pmod{23}$$

then use [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) for $(-3)^{22} \pmod{23}$.

Answer (score 3):

Bracket expansion and Fermat's little theorem gives
$$
(1-20)(1+20+\cdots + 20^{21}) = 1-20^{22}\equiv 1-1 = 0\pmod{23}
$$
And since $-19$ multiplied by your sum is congruent to $0$ modulo $23$, and $-19$ is coprime to $23$, that means the sum itself must also be congruent to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{i=0}^{21}{20}^i=\frac{1-{20}^{22}}{1-20}$...  But ${20}^{22}\cong 1\pmod{23}$ by Fermat's little theorem...

Answer (score 1):

Sum is equal to $\frac{20^{22}-1}{20-1}=\frac{20^{22}-1}{19}$,
but $20^{22}\cong 1 \mod 19,23$.